# Dynamically read files from Sdcard

Tags: android, dynamic, android-file

Guys i have a text file in sdcard i need to read that file.

Below is my code to read files:

```
 File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/f1.txt");
       fileIS = new FileInputStream(f);
            BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileIS));
           String readString = new String(); 
           //just reading each line and pass it on the debugger
           while((readString = buf.readLine())!= null){
              textdata.setText(readString);
              Log.d("line: ", readString);
           }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e){
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But i need to read files from sdcard dynamically.

here i have given it as `f1.txt`

Comment: What you actually mean by the word "Dynamically" ? thanks

Comment: why thanks? Dunamically means i need not provide the file name it will pick up the file at runtime

Comment: okay you want to let the user to enter the file name or you want all the file's name that exist in the directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/audio");
if (f.isDirectory())
{
    String files[] = f.list();
    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
    {
        Log.d("", files[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: i have files in one specific dir i.e., audio in sdcard does it pick up from there?

Comment: Just put path to your directory inside File object constructor

Comment: one last question i need to pass this files[i] value into soundpool where shall i do it sound1 = mSoundPool.load(files[i], 1); it showing me error arrayindex out of bound exception

Comment: It sounds like you are getting element from array which doesn`t exist, try to use for each loop instead of for: for(String file : files){ Log.d("", files[i]);}

Comment: hey i need help from u ?will plz help

Comment: replace  for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
    {
        Log.d("", files[i]);
    } to for(String file : files){ Log.d("", files[i]);}

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8444/discussion-between-dmytrodanylyk-and-goofy)